# use dynaTree without node icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynatree

dynaTree always shows icons for its nodes (part 1).

Is it possible to turn off the node icons and make it show like image part 2?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "icon": false in the node data to remove the icon.

Comment: I wish there were an easier way, like setting a property during tree creation. I have to send `icon:false` in every node which increases json data size transfered from server to client

Comment: Fancytree introduced a global option for this.

Comment: @Bistro: mar10's answer was unclear, so you misunderstood it. Actually you don't have to set it for every node. Jump at line 3264 of `jquery.dynatree.js` and change the `icon:` value from `null` to `false`. This makes the setting global to the tree. The configuration for the whole tree are lines 3257 and after.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Answer for myself to review later:

Disable it globally:

```
$.ui.dynatree.nodedatadefaults["icon"] = false; // Turn off icons by default
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Open** `jquery.dynatree.js` **in a text editor** like [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) or notepad.
2. Search for `$.ui.dynatree.nodedatadefaults` near the end of the file, at line 3257.
3. **Edit line 3264** by changing the value for `icon` from `false` to `null`.

```
/*******************************************************************************
     * Reserved data attributes for a tree node.
     */
    $.ui.dynatree.nodedatadefaults = {
        (...)
        icon: false, // Use a custom image (filename relative to tree.options.imagePath). 'null' for default icon, 'false' for no icon.
      (...)
    };
```

This will remove the default icon near to the expandable node.